# Help with ケ in this sentence/phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence

I'm still learning japanese, so I'd like someone to help me with this, please!

I can't understand the meaning of this phrase/expression:

> そっちのケはないんじゃ

I do understand the meaning of はないんじゃ, but I don't know what does "そっちのケ" means. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「そっちのケ」, or [「そのケ」](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B1), [「その[気]{け}」](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E6%B0%97%20%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%91), is a euphemism for "interest in the same gender", "homosexuality".

E.g.
そっちのケがある → have an interest in the same gender
そっちのケはない → have no interest in the same gender

<sub>The ケ comes from...</sub>

> <sub>け【気】
>
>   〘接尾〙《名詞、動詞の連用形、形容詞・形容動詞の語幹などに付いて》そのような様子・気配が感じられる意を表す。「[人気]{ひとけ}・毒気（どくけ/どっけ）・[食]{く}い[気]{け}・[寒気]{さむけ}」「[嫌気]{いやけ}がさす」▷「しゃれっけ」「商売っけ」のように促音「っ」がはいることもある。
>
>   (明鏡国語辞典)</sub>

Comment: これは「xな気がする」の意味を含んでいますか。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @QING この「[気]{け}」は元は「[気]{き}」と関連があるのだろうと思いますが、「～の[気]{け}がある」には「～な[気]{き}がする」という意味はないと思います。